# How to Download File PDF From URL to Phone in Cordova

Tags: cordova

i already use **cordova-plugin-file-transfer** but still cant work.
I have file pdf on 
**https://e-learning.linkstudycenter.com/media/attachment/matematika_A13-Paket1.pdf**
i will download it to phone and view the file in myapp, how to do that in cordova?

Answer (score -1):

this is the function to download and open an PDF :

**javascript :**

```
  function downloadAndOpenPdf() {
      let downloadUrl = 'https://e-learning.linkstudycenter.com/media/attachment/matematika_A13-Paket1.pdf';
      let path = this.file.dataDirectory;
      const transfer = this.ft.create();

      transfer.download(downloadUrl, path + 'matematika_A13-Paket1.pdf').then(entry => {
        let url = entry.toURL();

        if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
          this.document.viewDocument(url, 'application/pdf', {});
        } else {
          this.fileOpener.open(url, 'application/pdf')
            .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
            .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
        }
      });
    }
```

**html :**

```
 <button onclick="downloadAndOpenPdf()">Open PDF</button>
```

Comment: I got an error => 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataDirectory' of undefined,
then i change to: cordova.file.dataDirectory,
then I got error again =>
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Comment: path change depending on OS (IOS/android) please read that link https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files and try other path instead of this.file.dataDirectory